# Python - Classification algorithms implementation which accept missing values?

Tags: classification, python, missing-data

I've a binary classification problem which I want to solve where many features have a lot of missing values.

I know that imputing with mean/median/variance is a solution, but I'd like to run tests only with the original dataset without imputing. XGBoost allows the presence of missing values, while all the scikit-learn algorithms don't (correct me if I'm wrong), even if theoretically algorithm like random forest could accept missing values.

Other than XGBoost, which other python classification algorithms implementations allow the usage of a dataset with missing values?

Comment: Instead of trying to work with NaN values, most people either exclude the observations with missing data (which is bad) or use [tag:imputation]  (better). As always, the best strategy is to just collect complete data (but that's sometimes impossible because life is unfair).

Comment: If I'd exclude observations with missing data, probably my dataset would end up being empty :)

Comment: @Sycorax I think NA and NaN are different things

Comment: allowing NaNs is just an euphemism to imputation of some sort

Comment: @hxd1011 Depends on how NaNs arise. I'm assuming that OP didn't do something silly like take $\log(x)$ for a vector $x$ which contains 0s, or divide by zero...

Comment: It's worth emphasizing that replacing missing values with the mean is one of the worst imputation strategies. Modern imputation is model-assisted, such as assuming that the missing data is conditionally multivariate normal (e.g. the approach adopted by the Amelia II software). And @Aksakal 's point remains, which is that an ML algorithm which directly accommodates missing values are doing their own form of imputation (which in some cases is simply casewise deletion or mean-value-infill, both of which are worse than model-based imputation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the *h2o* package in python, it can deal with missing values.

Random Forest : http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/drf.html#faq

Gradient Boosting: http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/gbm-faq/missing_values.html

XGBoost: http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/xgboost.html#faqs